# I uninstalled WiFi driver by mistake

Tags: drivers, wireless

So I am new to this stuff and I was actually trying to disable bluetooth and instead I removed WiFi proprietary driver by mistake. Now I'm trying to enable it back but it needs an internet connection to download it again, and the Ethernet is not working.

(The driver was already present when I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Comment: Connect your phone with USB.

Comment: Can you interrupt the boot process and, at the GRUB prompt, boot into an earlier kernel version? Does the wireless work there? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.